# Executing xp_cmdshell to Generate a CSV -- Doesn't Like 'WHERE' Clause in Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
USE MyFakeDB
GO

DECLARE @month VARCHAR(16) 
SET @month = 'October2021'
;

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000)
    , @sql NVARCHAR(max)
    , @return INT
    , @filepath VARCHAR(512)
    , @servername VARCHAR(255) = @@ServerName
    , @username VARCHAR(255) = 'me'
    , @password VARCHAR(255) = 'password1234'
    , @dbname VARCHAR(255) = 'MyFakeDB'
    , @tablename VARCHAR(255) = 'Monthly_Insert'
    , @folderpath VARCHAR(255) = 'E:\SomeData\Monthly'  
    , @filename VARCHAR(255) = '' +@month+ '_Inserts.csv'
    , @datadate NVARCHAR(255) = 'WHERE DataMonth = ''' +@month+ ''''
;

SET @cmd = 'Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query ''SELECT Medium, RunDate, RunTime, UTCDate, UTCTime FROM '+@dbname+'.dbo.'+@tablename+' '+@datadate+ ';'' -Database '+@dbname+' -Server "'+@servername+'" -Username '+@username+' -Password '+@password+
        ' | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content -Path '+@folderpath+'\'+@filename+' -Encoding UTF8'
SET @cmd = 'powershell.exe -noprofile -command "'+@cmd+'"'
EXEC @return = xp_cmdshell @cmd, no_output
    IF @return <> 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'ERROR: '+@cmd
    END
;
GO
```

When I try running it, I get an

> ERROR: powershell.exe -noprofile -command *blah blah blah*

error. If I remove the `@datadate` variable (which is effectively just the `WHERE` clause), it works just fine.

I've also tried to do it without a variable for the `WHERE` clause, and just writing the literal string and it still doesn't work, which leads me to believe it doesn't like to have a `WHERE` clause.

Any ideas why?

Thanks,

Comment: You’re using T-SQL to call xp_cmdshell to call PowerShell to call Invoke-SqlCmd? I wonder if we can take any of these steps away?

Comment: Also, instead of showing us what _generates_ `@cmd`, could you `PRINT @cmd;` and show us _that_? And show us the actual error instead of `blah blah blah` which is completely useless to us?

Comment: There's so many levels of indirection, it's not surprising you're getting syntax errors. Why don't you just do this from Powershell in the first place? You could do this in about 3 lines. Make sure to parameterize your query properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing powershell scripts via the `-command` argument is notoriously tricky.

Instead use `-command -` which instructs Powershell to read the script from stdin, which you can provide in cmd.exe with the `<` redirection operator.

EG

SET @cmd = 'powershell.exe -noprofile -command - < '+@cmd

And this also allows you to send multi-line powershell scripts, which are easier to read, eg

```
SET @cmd = 'Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query ''SELECT Medium, RunDate, RunTime, UTCDate, UTCTime FROM '+@dbname+'.dbo.'+@tablename+' '+@datadate+ ';'' -Database '+@dbname+' -Server "'+@servername+'" -Username '+@username+' -Password '+@password+ '
          | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation 
          | Set-Content -Path '+@folderpath+'\'+@filename+' -Encoding UTF8'
```

And when debugging always print your cmd before running it, and don't suprress the output.

```
SET @cmd = 'powershell.exe -noprofile -command - < '+@cmd

print @cmd

EXEC @return = xp_cmdshell @cmd
IF @return <> 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'ERROR: '+@cmd
END
;
```